# How to select lines based on how many CONSECUTIVE times a PATTERN is present in a specific column field?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am stuck in a quite simple problem. I hope you can help me
I have a huge file that looks like that:

```
32 Q beta
33 S beta
34 A nb
35 T nb
36 G nb
37 T nb
38 K nb
39 T nb
40 D nb
41 T beta
42 P beta
43 I nb
44 Q nb
45 K nb
46 V nb
50 I beta
51 S beta
52 V beta
53 V beta
54 T beta
```

It always start with a line where $3= "beta".
I would like to save only the rows that contain a specific number of times (<=5) the pattern "non-beta" in the 3rd column, and copy only the previous/following lines where 3rd column is equal to "beta" (despite the numbers of these lines).

So the output would be:

```
41 T beta
42 P beta
43 I nb
44 Q nb
45 K nb
46 V nb
50 I beta
51 S beta
52 V beta
53 V beta
54 T beta
```

could you please help me?
thank you all

Comment: `I would like to save only the rows that contain a specific number of times (<=5) the pattern "non-beta"` The "rows" should contain? So `60 T betabetabetabetabeta` would be a row containing 5 times the pattern beta, right? `copy only the previous/following lines where 3rd column is equal to "beta"` I see no "copy", the lines in output are not duplicated. Did you mean "output"? If you meant that, why is `nb` in the output?

Comment: Hi KamilCuk, thanks for your help. So each row has to be copied as it is in the first file ( e.g : "50 I beta") without any modifications. For the "nb" lines, I want to copy them ONLY if they are repeated a maximum of 5 times in the first file. For the "beta" lines, I want to keep only ALL those that are immediately before or immediately after. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What if the pattern is like 2 x beta, 2 x nb, 2 x beta, 2 x nc, 2 x beta - how many times do you want to output the betas between nb and nc?

Comment: All the times. for example if i have something like this: ```104 N beta 73
105 Y beta 74
106 L beta 75
107 N nb 76
108 G nb 77
109 L beta 78
110 K beta 79
111 L nb 80
112 Q nb 81
113 G nb 82
114 N beta 83
115 F nb 84
116 Y nb 85
117 N beta 86 ``` I would like to keep all the lines since the consecutive repetitions of nb is always <=5

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what is requested

```
grep -zPo '(^|\n)(\S+\s\S+\sbeta\n)+(\S+\s\S+\s(?!beta).*\n){1,4}(\S+\s\S+\sbeta\n)+' file.txt  | tr '\0' '\n'
```

However may not do exactly what you expect: when many (<=5) the pattern non-beta are separated by beta lines the next match will not be find because of beta lines already consumed. The pattern should be changed depending what is really needed.

Comment: Hi Nahuel, thank you for your kind reply. Could you explain me better in what cases, your line does not work? I do not understand.  Thank you

Comment: it depends on how the non-beta pattern can be repeated around beta pattern. The current pattern matches one or more beta lines followed by 1 to 4 non beta lines followed by one or more (greedy) beta lines, so after the match if another non beta lines occurs it will not be taken because the last beta lines would be already consumed from input

Comment: Thanks! I got the problem. Another option could be using the line proposed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327973/how-to-select-rows-based-on-how-many-consecutive-times-a-number-is-present-in-a But in this case  I need to add a 4th column with   sequential numbers (where  I keep the same number for all consecutive "beta" or "nb" then switch to the next number and so on).. but it is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

The following perl script seems to work, as far as I was able to understand the requirements and test it.

- `-n` reads the input line by line and executes the script for each line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- the variable `$printing` is used to indicate we want to print the betas after a section we printed.
- the variable `$count` coutns how many lines a section has
- the variable `$previous` contains the third column of the previous line.
- the array `@buffer` accumulates the lines we *might* print later.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lan
if ($F[2] eq 'beta') {
    if ($printing) {
        print;
    } elsif ($previous eq 'beta') {
        push @buffer, $_;
    } elsif ($count && $count <= 5) {
        print for @buffer, $_;
        @buffer = ();
        $printing = 1;
    } else {
        @buffer = $_;
    }
} else {
    $printing = 0;
    if ($previous eq $F[2]) {
        ++$count;
        push @buffer, $_;
    } elsif ($previous eq 'beta') {
        $count = 1;
        push @buffer, $_;
    } elsif ($count <= 5) {
        print for @buffer;
        @buffer = $_;
        $count = 1;
    } else {
        @buffer = $_;
        $count = 1;
    }
}
$previous = $F[2];

END {
    if ($count <= 5) {
        print for @buffer;
    }
}
```